# why doesn't my string support the item Assignment

Tags: string, python-3.6

the idea here is to  be able to take a user input witch is `Main` and shuffle its value and re-enter it into the `Second` Entry, error message :    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

```
from tkinter import *
import random


def randomize(a):
    Second.delete(0 , 'end')
    b = Main.get()
    c = random.shuffle(b)
    Second.insert(0 , c)








root = Tk()



Main = Entry(root)
Main.grid(row = 1,column = 0 , sticky = 'we')

Second = Entry(root)
Second.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')


randombutton = Button(root , text = 'Randomize')
randombutton.grid(row = 3 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
randombutton.bind('<Button-1>' , randomize)
```

Comment: Could you please amend your question to provide the FULL traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call `random.shuffle` on a string, which is not possible (also, you are trying to assign the output of this to `c`, which will just return `None`). Instead you may want to convert it to a list, and then back into a string to output it within `Second`.

See the following code:

```
def randomize(a):
    Second.delete(0 , 'end')
    b = Main.get()
    c = list(b)
    random.shuffle(c) # Converted to a list, so it can be shuffled, see note for extra info
    Second.insert(0 , ''.join(c)) # Converted back into a string so it can be displayed
```

Note: `random.shuffle` does not return any values, it simply shuffles (and therefore changes) the variable which you put into it. For example, in the code `c = random.shuffle(b)`, `b` would NOW equal some random shuffling of whatever was in the entry box, whereas `c` would now equal `None`, as `random.shuffle` returns nothing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the value inserted isn't shuffed for some reason

Comment: there we go :)n

Comment: @CodingRonald, there was a typo in my answer, does this work for you?

Comment: @CodingRonald If the question is correct, please mark it as the answer, so those with a similar problem to you may find it